# If a certain selected cell is in row2, select value of row1 in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Alright so I have two columns one called "id", other one called "note".

My plan to make it so that when users doubleclick the ID something happens (a website containing that ID opens in a webbrowser control).

However if the user would doubleclick on the note, it obviously couldn't open the site with the ID, so what I want to do it when the user doubleclicks on a note that it selects the 'id' value in that row and uses that to open the webbrowser.

Anyone have any clue how to do this?

tl;dr: I want to select cell with name 'id' in the selected row

Comment: Is it two rows or columns ? and how are you handling the double click for id ? please post some code

Answer (score 0):

Use the CellClick or DoubleClick event.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int row = e.RowIndex;
        int column = e.ColumnIndex;

        //using DataGridview or DataSource with the row or column indexes to get the ID
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I made it select the entire row instead (which is more clean anyway)
and and then this code will select the first selected cell (meaning the first cell of the row)

```
public void SelectIdCell()
    {
        favorite_GridView.ClearSelection();
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in favorite_GridView.CurrentRow.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.Visible)
            {
                cell.Selected = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```